# Adding padding to TableRow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add padding to my table rows.

This is what I have:

```
var list = (report['items'] as List)
          .map((item) => 
          TableRow(children: [
                Text(item['place']),
                Text(item['type']),
                Text(item['producer']),
                Text(item['serial_number']),
                Text(formatter.format(DateTime.parse(item['next_check_date']))
                    .toString()),
                Text(item['test_result']),
                Text(item['comments']),
              ]))
          .toList();
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
var list = (report['items'] as List)
          .map((item) =>
      Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(10.0),
          child: TableRow(children: [
                Text(item['place']),
                Text(item['type']),
                Text(item['producer']),
                Text(item['serial_number']),
                Text(formatter.format(DateTime.parse(item['next_check_date']))
                    .toString()),
                Text(item['test_result']),
                Text(item['comments']),
              ])))
          .toList();
```

But I get this error ( after adding the Container with the padding):

```
The argument type 'TableRow' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.
```

How I can add padding to my Table / TableRows?

Comment: if you find my answer the most appropriate, could you please mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 5):

What I found working in this case (when you want to add padding between rows in a table) is to wrap `Text` Widget with `Container` and add `padding` property to one of your elements (that is potentially the 'tallest' one) and use `alignment` property for other containers where you need to align text within the row. My example will look like the following (sorry for the image being blurry):

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32.0, 0.0, 32.0, 0.0),
  child: Table(
    columnWidths: {
      0: FractionColumnWidth(.75),
    },
    children: achievementList
        .map(
          (achivement) => TableRow(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  achivement.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Text(
                  achivement.dateString,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
        .toList(),
  ),
),
```

where `achievementList` is my object with `title` and `dateString`. By first wrapping the `Text` Widget with `Container` and giving that first `Container`  property `padding: EgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),` it gives padding to the whole row.

[image: list with padding between items]

Comment: I realized that tables align the content to the top of each cell by default. I found it weird that your line ` alignment: Alignment.centerRight,` only aligned the content to the right. It did not align it to the center vertically. Had to use a TableCell widget and use the `verticalAlignment` parameter to align the content vertically.

Answer (score 2):

- Adding Space Between `TableRow`

[image]

```
    final attachmentWidget = Container(
    height: 200,
    width: width,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Palette.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
    child: Center(
      child: Table(
        children: [
          TableRow(
            children: [
              iconColumn(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  icon: Icons.camera_alt,
                  name: 'Camera',
                  tap: null),
              iconColumn(
                  color: Palette.defaultColor,
                  icon: Icons.photo,
                  name: 'Camera Gallery',
                  tap: null),
              iconColumn(
                  color: Palette.defaultColor,
                  icon: Icons.videocam,
                  name: 'Video',
                  tap: null),
              iconColumn(
                  color: Palette.defaultColor,
                  icon: Icons.photo,
                  name: 'Video Gallery',
                  tap: null),
            ]
          ),
          TableRow(
            children: [
              VerticalSpacing(height: 15),//SizeBox Widget
              VerticalSpacing(height: 15),
              VerticalSpacing(height: 15),
              VerticalSpacing(height: 0),
            ]
          ),
          TableRow(
            children: [
              iconColumn(
                  color: Palette.mediumBlue,
                  icon: Icons.insert_drive_file,
                  name: 'Document',
                  tap: null),
              iconColumn(
                  color: Palette.chatGreen,
                  icon: Icons.audiotrack,
                  name: 'Audio',
                  tap: null),
              iconColumn(
                  color: Palette.chatGreen,
                  icon: Icons.location_on,
                  name: 'Location',
                  tap: null),
              VerticalSpacing(height: 0),
            ]
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
    );
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have borders, then it will look like there are many thin empty cells.

Comment: Your problem is different from the original question. My answer is for that specific for this question. Please refrain from unliking it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found so far (only way really) was to add a placeholder container of some height.  That forces the row to be at least that tall.  Then you may want to set the relative size of that column to something small.

```
  TableRow _buildRow(int index) {
    return TableRow(children: [
      Center(child: Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank), ),
      AutoSizeText("Info A", textAlign: TextAlign.center,maxLines: 1,maxFontSize: 20,),
      AutoSizeText("Info B", textAlign: TextAlign.center,maxLines: 1,maxFontSize: 20,),
      CustomTextField(
        controller: _nameController[index],
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        autoFocus: false,
        icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
        hint: "Name",
      ),
      Container(
        height: 40,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _pressMe,
          color: Colors.blue,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
          child: AutoSizeText("Press Me",
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white)),
        ),
      ),
      Container(height: 70,),  // This is the line that helps me!!
    ]);
  }
```

Here are the parameters to add to your final Table widget to make this "fake" column very small (see column index 5)

```
 defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
          columnWidths: {0: FractionColumnWidth(.05),
            1: FractionColumnWidth(.125),
            2: FractionColumnWidth(.125),
            3: FractionColumnWidth(.4),
            4: FractionColumnWidth(.2),
            5: FractionColumnWidth(.02)},
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your largest child widget with a container and add some vertical margin. This will create a baseline for how big each row is.
2. Set the defaultVerticalAlignment parameter of the Table. By default it is set to the top. I have chosen to use the middle in my example below.

**Here is an example where I give 10 pixels of padding on the top and bottom of each row.** I have added horizontalInside border to make it easy to see the padding.

[image]

```
        Table(
          defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
          border: const TableBorder(horizontalInside: BorderSide()),
          children: [
            TableRow(children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 75,
                child: const Text('widget 1'),
              ),
              const Text('widget 2'),
              const Text('widget 3'),
              const Text('widget 4'),
              const Text('widget 5'),
              const Text('widget 6'),
              const Text('widget 7'),
            ]),
            TableRow(children: [
              const Text('widget 1'),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 75,
                child: const Text('widget 2'),
              ),
              const Text('widget 3'),
              const Text('widget 4'),
              const Text('widget 5'),
              const Text('widget 6'),
              const Text('widget 7'),
            ]),
            TableRow(children: [
              const Text('widget 1'),
              const Text('widget 2'),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 75,
                child: const Text('widget 3'),
              ),
              const Text('widget 4'),
              const Text('widget 5'),
              const Text('widget 6'),
              const Text('widget 7'),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score -1):

use sized box

```
TableRow(children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                  ),
                  Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.check,
                      size: 16, color: Colors.green),
                  Text('Testing'),
                ]),
```

Comment: This adds an additional column

Answer (score -2):

because TableRow isn't type of Widget.
you can use this

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
  child: Table(
    children: (report['items'] as List)
      .map((item) =>
      TableRow(children: [
        Text(item['place']),
        Text(item['type']),
        Text(item['producer']),
        Text(item['serial_number']),
        Text(formatter.format(DateTime.parse(item['next_check_date']))
            .toString()),
        Text(item['test_result']),
        Text(item['comments']),
      ]))
      .toList()
  ),
);
```

Comment: Got this error - `Error: The argument type 'TableRow' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Container'.`

Comment: Cant assign container to the TableRow